# How to use toggleClass with the same classed divs but without affecting the other ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, code-duplication

I am currently looking for a solution which aims at creating several of these boxes with this hover effect. 
The easiest solution would be to duplicate the code each time and change the id. Now I am looking for a better and more lean solution to achieve several duplications of the example shown in the snippet.

Any hints are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

```js
$(".rsausschreibung").hover(function() {
  $(".lsausschreibung").toggleClass("small large");
  $(".rsausschreibung").toggleClass("small large");
});
```

```css
.annonce {
  margin-left: 30px; 
  width: auto;
}

.lsausschreibung {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -10px;   
  background-color: white;    
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.large {
  height: 320px;
  width: 280px; 
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
}

.small {
  height: 290px; 
  width: 230px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.rsausschreibung {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="annonce">
    <div class="lsausschreibung large">
    </div>
    <div class="rsausschreibung small">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a class selector inside the hover function, use a reference to the targetted element with `$(this)`:

```
$(".rsausschreibung").hover(function() {
  $(this).prev().toggleClass("small large");
  $(this).toggleClass("small large");
});
```

That way you are always targetting the element on which the `mouseover` is happening, regardless of whether other elements are targetted overall by the `hover` method.

```js
$(".rsausschreibung").hover(function() {
  $(this).prev().toggleClass("small large");
  $(this).toggleClass("small large");
});
```

```css
.annonce {
  margin-left: 30px; 
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.lsausschreibung {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -10px;   
  background-color: white;    
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.large {
  height: 320px;
  width: 280px; 
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
}

.small {
  height: 290px; 
  width: 230px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.rsausschreibung {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="annonce">
    <div class="lsausschreibung large" id="el1">
    </div>
    <div class="rsausschreibung small" id="el2">
    </div>


</div>

<div class="annonce">

    <div class="lsausschreibung large" id="el3">
    </div>
    <div class="rsausschreibung small" id="el4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Some adjustments to the stylesheet were necessary for proper display, check the snippet.